# No Records Returned in Left Join with Inequality in MS Access

Tags: left-join, ms-access-2013, inequality

## Description

Hi,

I have a query using the same table twice in a left join with a inequality, but it does not produce any records, even though I am using a left join. I use MS Access 2013.

## Code

The code is:

```
SELECT DCT01A.*,
       DCT01B.*

FROM             utb_DCT_01_DailyConversionTrends AS DCT01A

       LEFT JOIN utb_DCT_01_DailyConversionTrends AS DCT01B

       ON            DCT01A.[Hour]          = DCT01B.[Hour]
                 AND DCT01A.[WeekDay]       = DCT01B.[WeekDay]
                 AND DCT01A.[Specification] = DCT01B.[Specification]
                 AND INT(DCT01A.[Date])     > INT(DCT01B.[Date])
```

## Data

I am expecting (at the moment, though this will change later) that an inner join would result in no records produced. This is due to that this is only test data and the dates only span two days.

Hour and WeekDay refers to the current the hour of the day and the week day number in the week. Specification is an ID. Date is that date, which include time.

## Goal

My goal of this query is to find all previous data on the same week day and hour, without picking the current record again (hence an inequality).

I realise I can simply run the inequality as >= instead, and then remove the = records afterwards. So I do have a simple workaround, I just can't understand why it won't work when written as above.

Thank you all for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT * FROM 

(
SELECT DCT01A.*,
       DCT01B.*

FROM             utb_DCT_01_DailyConversionTrends AS DCT01A

       LEFT JOIN utb_DCT_01_DailyConversionTrends AS DCT01B

       ON            DCT01A.[Hour]          = DCT01B.[Hour]
                 AND DCT01A.[WeekDay]       = DCT01B.[WeekDay]
                 AND DCT01A.[Specification] = DCT01B.[Specification]
                 AND INT(DCT01A.[Date])     >= INT(DCT01B.[Date])
)

WHERE 
DCT01A.[Date] <> DCT01B.[Date]
```

Kindest regards..

Comment: Hi,   Thanks for your help, though this still produces no records, as the only matches is for the same date and time (due to my limited data). I understand this will be fine, when I have more dates and times in my dataset, but I would like it so that DCT01A always shows, even if there are no matches (excl. '=' matches).   Thank you.